# Excel Range inside IF formula - DE-DUPE

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have a very long list in excel. I'm trying to de-dupe without re-organising the list. I have done a lot of de-duping before and I would normally just organise the list and use the below simple IF statement:

```
    =IF(A2=A1,"DUPLICATE FOUND","no dupe")
```

However I have a list with 15,000 rows of data and I need to see if any two rows contain the same data:

```
    =(IF(A2=(A1:A15000),"DUPLICATE FOUND","no dupe"))
```

So my question is what the heeby jeebies is wrong with my second statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIF` can be used with unsorted lists

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$15000,A1)>1,"DUPLICATE FOUND","no dupe")
```

Also, if you don't want to use a helper column, then excel has a 'Highlight Duplicates' conditional formatting:

[image: Image from Excel 2010]

Comment: Thanks Sean your a star!

Answer (score 1):

Use Advanced filter with copy to a new location and Unique values only - or Remove Duplicates.

A2=(A1:A15000) will only test for A2=A1.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer!! This works fine, I forgot to mention (quite crucially) that I still need those duplicate items in the list to remain, but be aware that there is a duplicate. Thanks!